# @Check (and its associated method) is never run

Tags: java, playframework

I have a Security class that looks like this:

```
package controllers;

import play.Logger;

public class Security extends Secure.Security {
  static boolean authenticate(String username, String password) {
    return password.equals("banan");
  }

  static boolean check(String profile) {
    Logger.info("profile: %s", profile);
    if ("user".equals(profile)) {
      Logger.info("connected: %s", connected());
      return connected().equals("user");
    }

    return false;
  }

  static void onAuthenticated() {
    Logger.info("Login by user %s", connected());
  }

  static void onCheckFailed() {
    Logger.info("Check failed!", "omg");
  }

  static void onDisconnect() {
    Logger.info("Logout by user %s", connected());
  }

  static void onCheckFailed(String profile) {
    Logger.warn("Failed auth for profile %s", profile);
    forbidden();
  }
}
```

And a Controller that looks like this:

```
@Check("user")
@With(Security.class)
public class Person extends Controller {

  public static void create() {
    List<models.person.Person> persons = models.person.Person.find(
        "order by createdAt desc").fetch(10);

    render(persons);
  }
}
```

The check method never gets called. Not even the checkAccess (in the Secure class) gets called. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From looking at the code you have posted, the one error I can see (if you compare to the instructions on the [secure module page](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.0/secure#aAddingauthorizationchecka)), is that you should use `@With(Secure.class)`.

So, change your code from

```
@Check("user")
@With(Security.class)
public class Person extends Controller {
```

to

```
@Check("user")
@With(Secure.class)
public class Person extends Controller {
```